# Sort a simple List of Objects

Tags: java

I get two objects from the database and I need to order it by the rowNumber (in this case it's already ordered) http://prntscr.com/hykvqn

I need to return a String[] with the `testFlow.name`

```
private int id;
private String name;
private TestCase testCase;
private int rowNumber;
private TestType testType;
private String params;
private String creationDate;
private String createdBy;

List<TestFlow> testFlow = hibernateSession.createQuery("FROM TestFlow WHERE name= :testFlowName").setParameter("testFlowName",testFlowName).list();
//Sort it and send the testCase flow by order
Collections.sort(testFlow)
```

Comment: Please post a syntactically complete class definition, not just a bunch of fields. And if you only want to sort two objects, what is the difficulty you are having? What have you tried yourself?

Comment: it's get an sets dude. I have a `List<TestFlow>` and I need to order the objects by  rowNumber

Comment: @sda should be easy enough to write a compilable example then.

Answer (score 1):

As rowNumber seems to be a field of your object I assume that it's also a column in your table. In that case you can just add "ORDER BY rowNumber" to your HQL query and don't use Collections.sort

Answer (score 0):

You need a Comparator which can sort by your desired criteria:

```
Comparator<? super TestFlow> comparator = new Comparator<TestFlow>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(TestFlow o1, TestFlow o2) {
        return o1.getRowNumber().compareTo(o2.getRowNumber());
    }
};
testFlow.sort(comparator);
```

And if you're using Java 8 or 9, this can be reduced to:

```
testFlow.sort(Comparator.comparing(TestFlow::getRowNumber));
```